# google bigquery query on firebase functions

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I try to get data from a google bigquery database in my firebase cloud funtions.

```
exports.corsEnabledFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    res.status(204).send("");
  } else {
    // Set CORS headers for the main request

    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    let bigquery = new BigQuery();
    const query = "SELECT * FROM `mydb-2094d.logs.eventlogs` LIMIT 10";
    bigquery.query(query, (err, results) => {
       if (err) {
           console.log("error", err);
       }

       console.log("results", results);
       res.send(results);
    }
   });
  }
});
```

results are always null. The table is not empty.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the entire minimal function that doesn't work the way you expect, along with all logs that it generates?

Comment: I edited but don't think that it helps

Comment: Could you show the logs as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`BigQuery.query()` definition](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/BigQuery#query) it expects the callback to have signature `(err, rows)`, so it looks like your callback is looking at the error rather than the actual results. Try:

```
bigquery.query(query, (err, results) => {
    console.log("results", results);
    res.send(results);
}
```